# Grails Gorm Multitenant setup not working properly

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant

I have a grails project having multi tenant setup but is not working properly
Project config

```
grailsVersion=5.0.0
grailsGradlePluginVersion=5.0.0
groovyVersion=3.0.7
gormVersion=7.1.0
```

If the hibernatestore is added in BootStrap everything works fine

```
class BootStrap {

    HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore
    DatabaseProvisioningService databaseProvisioningService

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def databaseConfiguration = databaseProvisioningService.findDatabaseConfiguration("dbName")
        hibernateDatastore.getConnectionSources().addConnectionSource(databaseConfiguration.dataSourceName, databaseConfiguration.configuration)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

But same code if called during runtime on say user login

```
class AuthenticationController
{
  static scope="session"

  HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore
  AuthenticationService authenticationService
  DatabaseProvisioningService databaseProvisioningService

  def index() {}

  def login()
  {
    def loginId = params.get("loginId")
    def password = params.get("password")
    if (loginId != null && password != null)
    {
      def user = authenticationService.login(loginId, password)
      if(user)
      {
        session.user = user
        session.setAttribute(SessionTenantResolver.ATTRIBUTE, "dbName_" + user.tenant.id)

          if(!hibernateDatastore.getConnectionSources().getConnectionSource("dbName_" + user.tenant.id))
          {
            def databaseConfiguration = databaseProvisioningService.findDatabaseConfiguration("dbName_" + user.tenant.id)
            hibernateDatastore.getConnectionSources().addConnectionSource(databaseConfiguration.dataSourceName, databaseConfiguration.configuration)
          }
      }
    }

    redirect(controller: "user", action: "index")
  }


}
```

some methods starts failing with not an Entity error
Methods failing are

```
User.count()
User.save()
```

Methods working are

```
User.findById()
User.findByName()
```

Error stack

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:158)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi$_count_closure4.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:183)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class User

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:297)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:241)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:120)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.count(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:180)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.count(GormEntity.groovy:649)
    at com.ayuka.stobil.ClientService.$mt__getCount(ClientService.groovy:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2$_closure6.doCall(Tenants.groovy:265)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.executeWithExistingOrCreateNewSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:210)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore.withNewSession(AbstractHibernateDatastore.java:369)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2.doCall(Tenants.groovy:258)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$CurrentTenant.withTenant(Tenants.groovy:358)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.withId(Tenants.groovy:236)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.services.DefaultTenantService.withCurrent(DefaultTenantService.groovy:71)
    at com.ayuka.stobil.ClientController.$mt__indexJson(ClientController.groovy:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2$_closure6.doCall(Tenants.groovy:265)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:297)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:241)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.executeWithNewSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:153)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.executeWithExistingOrCreateNewSession(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:207)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateDatastore.withNewSession(AbstractHibernateDatastore.java:369)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$_withId_closure2.doCall(Tenants.groovy:258)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants$CurrentTenant.withTenant(Tenants.groovy:358)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.withId(Tenants.groovy:236)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.services.DefaultTenantService.withCurrent(DefaultTenantService.groovy:71)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Note : datastore is added properly in this scenario it shows up on checking with debug mode but domain class functionalities throw the above error

Tried adding the code to add datastore in Bootstrap class and everything started working